# Evaluating triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\iiint (xyz) dx\,dy\,dz$$
I am asked to evaluate this integral over the region $$D:=\left \{ (x,y,z) \in\mathbb{R}^3 :x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4 \wedge y > x\right \}$$
Here is the integral I set up:
$$\iint_{Pr_{y,x}(D)}\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}(xyz) dx dy dz$$=$$\iint_{Pr_{y,x}(D)}(xy)dx dy\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}(z)  dz$$
which integral of z is

$$\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}(z)  dz=(\frac{4-y^2-x^2-4+y^2+x^2}{2})=0$$

and then we get:

$$\iint_{Pr_{y,x}(D)}\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2-x^2}}(xyz) dx dy dz=0$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is correct. In fact, we can conclude this immediately without doing any calculations since the domain of integration is symmetric in $z$, while the function $xyz$ is odd in $z$, so the integral must be zero.

Comment: Thank you nesHan!